# What is this hex-like stuff in my POST to a InMagic Textworks system

Tags: html, forms, http, encoding

I am looking at the details of a POST request to an Inmagic TextWorks system in Chrome developer tools. If I drill down into the POST, I see this:

```
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
status:
mode:sort
currentPage:1
querySql:[PROCESSED]c:5f:2:61:58:-62:7:3 [bunch of stuff like this]
```

What am I looking at in querySql? My first thought was that it was Hex, but it contains negative numbers--and when I run it thru a hex to asci converter I get nonsense. My second thought was that it was URL encoding -- but it does not contain and percentages.  Clearly this is some kind of encoded SQL -- but how is SQL like this encoded? What is it? How can I tell what it means?

Comment: Yep, it appears to be a sequence of signed 8-bit hexadecimal numbers. But apart from that, I see nothing familiar about them. It could be anything; maybe some (binary) intermediate representation generated by a SQL precompiler? I'm just guessing here; to really understand its meaning, you need to understand the code that generated it. Please supply some details about whatever it is you referred to as 'someone else's code'.

Comment: Is it proprietary encoding by the app that generates it? Perhaps a security through obscurity measure by the vendor?

Answer (score 0):

According to [InMagic support](http://support.inmagic.com/dbtw-wpd/exec/dbtwpub.dll?BU=http%253A%252F%252Fsupport.inmagic.com%252Fsupbase2.htm&TN=kbase&QY=find%20%28ID=2104%29&RF=Full%20Article&DF=Full%20Article&MR=20&NP=2&RL=0&DL=0&XC=/dbtw-wpd/exec/dbtwpub.dll&ID=&AC=QBE_QUERY),

> When a user clicks on the 'submit query' button in a search form the
> browser gathers up the information in the search boxes and sends it to
> the server where WebPublisher can take the information submitted from
> a form and conduct a search. This information is grouped in name /
> value pairs and then encoded for transmission over the network.

If you continue to read you will see:

> This "Canned" query is constructed using the GET method to submit
> information to the CGI script. A standard Query to WebPublisher uses
> the POST method.

I believe what you see is part of this "Canned" query or a key/value matching.